# Unable to import merge module

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I'm attempting to create a Windows Installer for a custom DLL by following the directions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw2dz878.aspx).  I've gone through the steps multiple times verbatim, but keep receiving the error "unable to import merge module".  There are very few references on how to resolve this issue that I've been able to find.  Has anyone run across this and come up with a solution?

Found [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/696437/setup-project-build-fails-after-filling-in-keyoutput-mergemoduleproperties-module-retargetable-folder-error-unable-to-import-merge-module), but there seems to be no resolve yet.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help.  I ran into a similar issue after upgrade VS2008 to SP1 and then applying the patches to allow it to talk to TFS 2010.

It turns out that was a red herring.  I discovered that if I build the merge modules in VS2010 while running as Administrator, that I could not build the VS2008 setup packages referencing the merge modules.  (The setup packages in VS2008 were for legacy platform installs (read windows 2000).)

So if you are having a problem, and you are running VS with Administrator, that may be causing the problem.  Try doing the build without administrator privileges, and see if that works.